# Flutter - How to use mounted in GetX

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I initiate network request in GetXController, after network call back, I should judge this controller/this page is dealloc or not. If this page is not dealloced, update Page. If this page is dealloced, I do noting. As I know, I can write below codes in flutter origin:

```
if (mounted) {
   // update page
   setState({
   });
}
```

So my question is how to write in GetX controller?

Comment: you could use reactive objects to deal with such situation ... and moreover you may override the dispose method and could call your_controller.dispose() to dispose the controller if not mounted. And one more tip is to cancel the network request while disposing your controller.

Comment: you can use isClosed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property called `isClosed` in `GetxController`
so you can use it instead of `mounted`

```
class MyController extends GetxController{
...
  fun() {
    // some code
    if(this.isClosed) return;
    // code that you want not execute it
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mounted can only be called inside Stateful widgets, so you can't use it inside a Controller.

If you are using named routes I think you can get the current name of the page and do something.

```
if(Get.routing.current == "/home"){
   doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `mounted` bool is specific only for the `StateFulWidget`, I could think of passing it as a `Stream<bool>`to the controller, then use it, **But**, this is not the ideal solution and it can be very problematic.

On the other hand, you can check on `mounted` before calling the method, like this:

```
   // ....
   onPressed: () {
      if (mounted) {
        controller.sendRequest();
      }
    },
    // ....
```